# ASP.NET Dynamically add user controls and save to the database

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I am writing an asp.net site, in the database, I have a questions table and answersOptions table. I want to dynamically generate radio button or check box server control based on the database entry.

And also allow user to click submit button to save the user selected answers into database.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this article you will know how to add dynamic controls in ASP.NET http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/25/TRULY-Understanding-Dynamic-Controls-_2800_Part-1_2900_.aspx

Comment: Could you specify the url again, thanks

Comment: Just google this and you will get ASP.NET blog "TRULY UNDERSTANDING DYNAMIC CONTROLS (PART 1)"

Answer (score 0):

```
void getAnswers(){  SqlDataReader dr;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = constring;
        SqlCommand Answers = new SqlCommand();
        con.ConnectionString = constring;
        Answers = new SqlCommand("YourStoredProcedure'" + questionID + "'", con);

        try
        {

            con.Open();
            dr = Answers.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

            CheckBox answer = new CheckBox();
            answer.Text = dr[0].ToString(); // your datarow cosist of your stored procedures return state

            }

             finally
        {
            if (dr != null)
            {
                dr.Close();
            }
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
         }
        }
```

}

and on Page_Load call your function getAnswers(); i think this is the main idea